# Rails - Cannot create New rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I already have a live Rails application which is running in rails 5.0.1. Now, when I try to create new rails version I get the following error

```
Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.7.1) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I run 'bundle install' I get the following error

```
Could not find spork-1.0.0rc4 in any of the sources
```

How can I solve this error?

My System only have Rails 5.0.1 version and Ruby version 2.3.1.

PS: When I keep Ruby version in 2.2.5, I am able to create my rails app successfully.

Comment: try `bundle update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to create a new rails application, try setting it up in a new folder.

If you're trying to update the rails version of your current project update the rails version in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle update rails`.

Prepending the command that's giving you

```
Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.7.1) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

with `bundle exec` may solve your problem.

If you're using something like `rbenv` to manage your ruby version, you may have to update your `.ruby-version` file, and then run

```
rbenv install
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

to install that new version of ruby, bundler and your gems.